# how do I center a label i android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to align center the title or label in activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347341/how-to-align-center-the-title-or-label-in-activity)

Simple question, I have made a dialogbox with a label at the top. The label has for some reason gravity left as default, and I want to change it to center. The label is defined in my AndroidManifest.xml file as :

```
<b>activity</B> 
        android:name=".WelcomeDialog" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:label="@string/welcome_dialog_title"
        >

<b>/activity></B>
```

I have tried to put android:gravity="center" but it is not working, any tips how to solve this issue?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

just put the code under the setContentView(R.layout.new)...

```
((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

To be very frank this code is copied from another stackoverflow question:
[How to align center the title or label in activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347341/how-to-align-center-the-title-or-label-in-activity)

I am sure it can help you mate!!!!

;)