# Set Activity title ellipse to middle?

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity whose title keeps change, but sometimes its long and get ellipses by end. Can I set ellipse to middle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ((TextView) ((FrameLayout) ((LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) getWindow()
            .getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0))
            .setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MIDDLE);
```

got it from [android:set title bar in middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067490/androidset-title-bar-in-middle)

Comment: This is a hack. It's likely to break.

Comment: I agree, It does break with 3.0+, But works too with older :)

Answer (score 20):

You can do this:

```
    final int actionBarTitle = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    final TextView title = (TextView)getWindow().findViewById(actionBarTitle);
    if ( title != null ) {
        title.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MIDDLE);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the 1.6 in your question. It should be the same, but different id, try to find it using hierarchyviewer

Comment: This too is a hack. It's likely to break. At least check for nulls and catch exceptions.

Comment: @xmenW.K."android.R.id.title" in a non-actionbar version.

Answer (score 0):

if you user the Toolbar you can add this function before settitle

```
  private void setToolbarTextEllipsizeInMiddle(Toolbar toolbar){
    try {
        toolbar.setTitle("'");
        for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MIDDLE);
            }
        }//end for i
        toolbar.setTitle("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using `android:ellipsize`

Refer [android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize)  in the Android Developers page.

Comment: you cant use it on an Activity title, can you ?