# How to ellipsize an title of activity on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, title

I'm trying to ellipsize the title of an activity, could anyone please let me know how to do it?

```
setTitle("My Title");
//when the text of the title gets too long, how can I use setEllipsize() here? how can I get the view Id of that title?
```

Comment: So maybe check it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779037/set-activity-title-ellipse-to-middle

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://it-ride.blogspot.pt/2010/07/android-title-marquee.html
Some of the people there say it works, some others say it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

The code is based on this web link
 http://it-ride.blogspot.pt/2010/07/android-title-marquee.html

```
// make the title scroll!
         // find the title TextView
         TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.title);
         // set the ellipsize mode to MARQUEE and make it scroll only once

         title.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
         title.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(1);
         // in order to start strolling, it has to be focusable and focused
         title.setFocusable(true);
         title.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
         title.requestFocus();
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the code above doesn't work for me, but thanks anyway for the response!

Comment: what is the problem you are having and I will en devour to fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Alexander, the problem is I can't add ellipsis to the end of the text of the activity title when the text gets too long, so the text in the title will just be truncated.

Comment: findViewById(android.R.id.title) doesn't really return the view of the activity's title, so the code above doesn't work for me...

Comment: never mind, I just worked it out!! The trick is I need to setSingleLine(true) in order to ellipsize the text view. Thanks everyone for all the help!!