# Android find out if titlebar text is overflowing

Tags: android, titlebar

I have an Android application (4.0.3+). It is essentially a file explorer with some custom functionality. I set the title every now and again to reflect the path the user is currently at. However, on some longer paths, the title tends to overflow, like this:

```
/ storage / sdcard0 / mypath / subd...
```

However, I'd rather have it the other way around:

```
...card0 / mypath / subdir / subsubdir
```

Is it possible (and if so, how) to know whether or not the text in the title bar is overflowing (I didn't see any related methods in `Activity` apart from `setTitle()`)? Also, is it possible to have the text overflowing on the left side instead of the right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((TextView) ((FrameLayout) ((LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) getWindow()
            .getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0))
            .setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.START);
```

got it from [android:set title bar in middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067490/androidset-title-bar-in-middle)

Comment: Although my line is way longer than that (`TextView v = (TextView) ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) decorView).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0);`), I managed to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try out [setCustomView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29) in ActionBar. There you can have a TextView that [ellipzise](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) at the start.