# How to remove Extra Navigation drawer icon

Tags: android, navigation

How to remove pointed icon in Navigation Drawer, I just playing with Navigation Drawer, I just wanted to maintain only one icon and the title in center. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your onCreate() method.

```
    getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working. do me a favour i have to set that navigation drawer title in the center.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but may be this will be a help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-align-actionbar-title-center-in-android


and dont forget to accept my answer if it did the trick. thanks :)

Comment: @Jay, hey buddy it's working . but i have to set the navigation drawer title in the center.

Comment: If you want to title to center then create your own custom view and set title to center and you can add that custom view to actionbar.

Comment: check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-align-actionbar-title-center-in-android?lq=1