# How center custom dialog title on Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

I'm writing a custom dialog on android.
I did this using the onCreateView method.

```
public class CheckpointLongPressDialog extends DialogFragment {

public void CheckpointLongPressDialog() {}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkpoint_long_press_dialog, container);
    getDialog().setTitle("TITLE");
    return view;
}
```

How can i center the title programmatically?

Comment: Why stressing yourself by doing it **programmatically**, when you can simply alter the `fragment_checkpoint_long_press_dialog` xml file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android

Comment: @DerGolem you're right but i think there is a simple way to do this programmatically maybe

Comment: It's **simpler** to do that in the xml (**1 line** of code).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe its not the best way, I use a custom title TextView.

```
TextView title = new TextView(mainActivity);
title.setText(alertTitle);
title.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient);
title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // this is required to bring it to center.
title.setTextSize(22);
getDialog().setCustomTitle(title);
```

Comment: I try this way but I can't find the function `setCustomTitle(title)`

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem using a builder and inflating the xml layout.

```
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkpoint_long_press_dialog, null));


    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
final int titleId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
TextView title = (TextView) getDialog().findViewById(titleId);
if (title != null) {
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the whole layout to inflate also your custom title?. Instead of `getDialog().setTitle("TITLE");` you can also include a TextView in your custom layout for the title.

Answer (score 0):

The title view is using default theme. You have 2 ways to do what you want, first one is better for having a more customized experience:

1. Use this to have a dialog without title, and then make custom title bar in the layout of this fragment.

   dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
2. Extend the default theme for the dialog and update it, then set it in this dialog.