# Android center textview in custom ActionBar using a linearlayout horizontally and vertically

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, textview

I'm trying since several hours to center my title in the action bar horizontally. This is my code:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/actionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView 
                 android:id="@+id/activityTitle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my `onCreate()` code in my `activity`:

```
        this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/myfont.ttf");
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.activityTitle)).setTypeface(tf);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.activityTitle)).setText("Test");

        getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

The actionbar icon is hided and the title in the correct font, but it is only centered vertically, but not horizontally. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried setting the TextView width to match_parent and then add a gravity attribute to the TextView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android

Comment: @zgc7009 this answer works alone, but not together with my approch to change also the font of the action bar

Comment: @GaryBak yes I've tried that, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `RelativeLayout` and the properties

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

for example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Jorgesys was here!"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. The text is only centered, if I delete my java code and took only your code