# Custom ActionBar title is not being center aligned

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am creating a custom actionBar. everything is working fine but I have failed to put the text in the center of the actionBar. Searched the internet for the solutions there were many of them but none for me. Can anyone help me to achieve it. I tried to implement the following question's answer but it also had no effect.[How to center align the ActionBar title in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android)

**Though I can put the text in center by giving the padding to textview but I think that's not the proper approach.**

Below is the code:

Custom ActionBar Code:

```
private void createCustomActionBarTitle()
{
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#8B58A3")));

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);

    TextView frag1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleFragment1);
    frag1.setTypeface(vivaldiiFont);

    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
}
```

And xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleFragment1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

This is how the actionBar is now

[image]

this text should be in center not towards left.

Comment: Set `android:gravity="center"` for textview.

Comment: @PiyushGupta no effect still the same

Comment: Have you used `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);`  in your code?

Comment: yup I have used it as the answer to the question suggested but there was no effect to the text ...

Comment: Try to set `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); and getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE );` both.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes I tried both but it didn't had any effect on the text. that why I posted the question here no other solutions are working :)

Comment: Set `android:layout_gravity="center"` for `LinearLayout` too.

Comment: @PiyushGupta alas no effect .

Comment: follow this tutorial http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: @Chandru yeah that code is right nothing is wrong with it but it wasn't upto my requirements, Maybe that problem occurs with some devices ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

**1. custom_action_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/apptitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your code it wasn't helping but then I only wrote the xml from you answer and it worked... thanks

Comment: can you edit your answer and only write xml here so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/header" > 

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:textColor="@color/header_text_color"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Do it like this you will get as you want.

Comment: I have uploaded the image of actionBar text .. /

Comment: Make sure you changed your layout from Linear to Relative.. because Linear Layout cause problem in centre alignment.

Comment: I tried your answer as it is but it didn't effect the text

Comment: @BasantKumar Who told you that it creates a problem. Instead of it you need to learn that how can you use it.

Comment: @piyush i know how to use that .. we have to put empty view and use concept of weight with that ..

Comment: So you can't say this `because Linear Layout cause problem in centre alignment`