# Alignment in custom Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have created a custom action bar

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_draft);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionbarFeed = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.textView_blogtest);  
    actionbarFeed.setText("My Photos and videos");
```

The problem is Text View is not align center

[image]

In my layout the text view is at center. when it come to action bar it is shifted to right side.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_blogtest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
 <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/menu</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffca36</item>
    <item name="background">#f66605</item>
    <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/action_bar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post your custom XML layout?

Comment: Have you soled these problem?

Comment: I have done this issue with this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628064/3946958

Answer (score 0):

look for an answer here: [How to center align the ActionBar title in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android)

basically you should change your xml file for the action bar.

**EDIT:**

post your xml file for the action bar to get a more precise answer...

**EDIT2:**
i don't know it. But a hint for debugging: Set background color of your `textview` to another color and post a screenshot of it. From this you can see if the problem is that the content of `textview` is placed wrong, or the whole `textview` is not placed correctly.

Maybe you only need the line

```
android:gravity="center"
```

in your `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

please use below function for set actionbar

```
public void setMainScreenActionBar(String p_title)
{

        LayoutInflater m_inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ActionBar m_actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        View m_viewActionBar = m_inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_title_layout, null);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams m_params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
        TextView m_tvTitle = (TextView) m_viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.title);
        m_tvTitle.setText(p_title);
        m_actionBar.setCustomView(m_viewActionBar, m_params);
        m_actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        m_actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        m_actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        m_actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

custom_actionbar_title_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Write below code in your style.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>


     <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="background">@color/orange</item>
         <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_backarrow</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_backarrow</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: it will hide my navigation drawer icon .

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` method:

```
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null),
    new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        Gravity.CENTER
));
```

`custom_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Your title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you will have an `Actionbar` with just a title.

Comment: This will hide my navigation drawer icon on the left side

Comment: The shift that happen in action bat is due to the menu icon . Is there is any problem with my style?

Comment: why to use more than one relative..better use linear and give gravity