# Toolbar header's item alignment issue?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-toolbar, text-alignment

Today i have stucked in one of the weird problem in `Toolbar` custom header.
I am using the `TextView` in the center and `ImageView` which is at the right of the `Toolbar`. So i have used below lines of code in xml , please check it once.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#3EC3D6"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerTxt"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Tile"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/chat_new_icon"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And getting these output from above code.
[image]

I have used the `RelativeLayout` for it to come out from this problem, But it also NOT worked.Please check the below code for it

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#3EC3D6"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerTxt"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Tile"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/chat_new_icon"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And getting another unexpected result please check it once.
[image]

I have already refer this solution but it is not working for me.Please check the link once.
[1. First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)
[2. Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443604/android-how-to-center-title-in-toolbar) 
[3. Third Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font) 
[4. Forth Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210931/android-center-the-title-of-the-toolbar)

What i need that `TextView` should at the center of the `Toolbar` and `ImageView` should at the right of the `Toolbar`.Please help me to short out from this problem.

Comment: try to add app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"   in toolbar

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Have tried urs suggestion NOT worked :(

Comment: also try to set inner layout height to match parent

Comment: In your first layout there, just get rid of the `LinearLayout`. `Toolbar` accounts for its child `View`s' `layout_gravity` when laying itself out. You don't need to wrap them in another `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @MikeM sorry , I do not get u,please help me to short out from this

Comment: Remove the `LinearLayout` inside the `Toolbar` from the first layout you posted in the question.

Comment: OK.. I will try it as I will reach at office and let u know soon about it... Thanks for input

Comment: No problem. [Here's a somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41957875), and my answer there has an explanation of why that's not centering, and how exactly to setup the child `View`s, in case my comments aren't that clear. Do note that the `LinearLayout` there is used just to stack those two `TextView`s vertically. It doesn't fill the `Toolbar`, or hold everything in it.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for valueable comment works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@MikeM.** suggestion has worked for me. For more detail on the issue please refer this link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962801/3946958)

What i have done to get rid off from the problem is that I have removed the `LinearLayout` inside the `Toolbar`  and set the gravity of the view with help of `android:layout_gravity`, Please refer the below solution for it

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#3EC3D6"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headerTxt"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Tile"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/chat_new_icon" />


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And getting the expected result from above code, please check it once.
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code...edited your relative layout implementation

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerTxt"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Tile"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/chat_new_icon"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerTxt"
                         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Will you please give your @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay

Comment: Please check `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />`

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha i have posted second answer with complete toolbar layout its working please check...

Answer (score 0):

This is working ...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#3EC3D6"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerTxt"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Tile"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerTxt"
            android:src="@drawable/delete_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I have tried urs second solution , but it also not working,Please check the output from above code.  https://ibb.co/m7Zqzv

Comment: i have once again mention code and screen shot what output is coming , i posted it

Answer (score 0):

This is what comes at my end

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#3EC3D6"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerTxt"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Tile"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerTxt"
            android:src="@drawable/delete_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: What i need @MohdSaquib that , Title should be in center and image at the right..

Comment: In my solution i think your requirement is fulfilling , it will not comes at centre perfectly because of action bar property and rest of the thing is shown as in image i share.4

Comment: I need it center bro..That what i have asked the questin on SO.Thanks for urs value bale time