# How to add Tool bar title at the center of layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I searched a lot but i can't able to get proper answer.generally we use it as

```
toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_to_updates);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar=getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        bar.setTitle("Updates");
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android

Comment: it's about Actionbar title using newly updated toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found `Toolbar` but trying to make changes in `ActionBar`. They are different.
Check here [Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

Comment: That's What I'm Looking For.Thanks!

Comment: after declaring text view inside android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar you must required to set bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);