# Android Action Bar: Changing the color of Action Buttons and title to the center

Tags: android, action-button

[Here an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68FIM.jpg)

here is the pic please can  any one suggest me how to change the icon colour  and title to center to the action bar ...

Comment: Simply use "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" and customize your ActionBar as your like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12388200/3790150

Comment: You might need to create custom actionbar layout for that and you can add it to actionbar as display custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
change pading if you want.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: what error? your xml layout not display correctly ?

Comment: thank you @Govinda  , then how to add a edit text n button  in the layout so that  user can input its details and submit to the next page .. please suggest me and thank you for the help

Comment: back = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.back);
        setSupportActionBar(back);    back.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_navigate_before_white_24dp);
        back.invalidate()        here is the code i have tried still not working so can u suggest me where is my fault..

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this.**

**Create new layout custom_toolbar.xml in your project.**

**Add below code in above file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_events" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRight"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**And then add that layout to your toolbar xml file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Hope this will help you.**