# How do I center the ActionBar title in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, center, title

I want to center the `ActionBar` title text in my app...

I understand I need a custom layout to do this... So how do I do it?

I've tried following the instructions from here - [How to center align the ActionBar title in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android) -

but it's not clear where to put the code. I tried my best to follow the steps, but my action bar stayed exactly the same.

Thanks.

Base API for my app is 16.

Comment: you need a custom layout to do that, because default layout of actionbar can't do it. :D

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam Oh, okay... My only concern with a custom layout is that I'd lose my `DrawerLayout` and hamburger button... How can I create a custom layout without losing these then? Thanks.

Comment: how would you lose your `DrawerLayout` ? You can follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android) :D

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam That post doesn't have a clear answer... I've no idea where to put the code. I created a new xml and pasted the `getSupportActionBar()` codes in my `OnCreate`, but the action bar looks exactly the same.

Comment: Please consider to edit your question bro, and let us know what have you tried so far. You can post your snippet code too. :D
Please read [How To Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :D

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam Yeah, I get it. Thanks... I'll update my post when I can.

Answer (score 0):

[ActionBar with Custom View](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) will help you. It is clear and easy to follow.

Comment: Ok EA, I'll give this a try. Thanks :D