# Why is app name not showing in Toolbar in android?

Tags: java, android

The app name is not showing in the app-bar. Its white. i don't know why. please help. It was showing before. then i made lots of changes now is unable to fix it

In main activity

```
....
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


  ....

</RelativeLayout>
```

In styles

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set the adapter onto the view pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        // Connect the tab layout with the view pager. This will
        //   1. Update the tab layout when the view pager is swiped
        //   2. Update the view pager when a tab is selected
        //   3. Set the tab layout's tab names with the view pager's adapter's titles
        //      by calling onPageTitle()
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have app name specified in res>values>strings

Comment: You need to move the `myToolbar` initialization and `setSupportActionBar()` call to after `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either add this in your java file. It sets the `true` for show title bar property which makes it visible.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Or add this in your xml under toolbar element

```
app:title="@string/app_name"
```

`app` is used to denote properties included in support library widgets.

> Most important you should have `app_name` string in your `string.xml` file.

**For Title in Centre**

You have to design your own custom layout for action bar and set it to that. [How to set title in centre in ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12388200/6047274)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to align the text in center ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this..

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
myToolbar.setTitle("Your App Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

> In styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> </style>
```

Here is your problem. You put `NoActionBar` , that means it won't have the bar at top.

You should put `DarkActionBar` to have the default ActionBar you had before doing the changes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: app crashes - according to https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html we have to add it.  Using one of these themes prevents the app from using the native ActionBar class to provide the app bar.