# Actionbar title does not align vertically when using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-coordinatorlayout

So I've got a fragment with a CoordinatorLayout as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.susheel.pocketparliament.fragments.pages.HomeFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/colorAccent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="top">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/building_1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title="Title">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lorem"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the layout for my MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.susheel.pocketparliament.MainActivity">

    <!--This will be replaced with fragments-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/sidenav_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The fragment gets added using the FragmentManager to replace the FrameLayout. However, when I scroll up on the CoordinatorLayout, the title on my ActionBar isn't centered vertically. This is what happens:

[image]

[image]

How do I get the action bar title to center? Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry about the huge images

Comment: There isn't any simple way of doing this to my knowledge, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android

Comment: Do you know why this happens? It works fine when the entire thing is in the activity.

Comment: What do you mean? What is happening?

Comment: Why is it being misalligned like that?

Comment: The title is always aligned to the left. It's never aligned to the center unless there is some way that you can change that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Just use android:paddingBottom="10dp" inside your toolbar.

```
             <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                app:title="Title">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```