# How to change title's position in toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, title, android-titlebar

I have a `toolbar` in my activity (`actionbar` app is removed). In my `toolbar`, I have a title and icon. Now I want to move the title to the right with this code: `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` but the icon is also moved.
I want to move *only* the title to the right.

Toolbar code:

```
    <style name="ToolBar" parent="AppTheme">

    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorToolbar</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorToolbar</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>

</style>
```

Activity.java :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_addNewItem);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("کلاس جدید");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android

Comment: you need to create your own implementation of the toolbar with a textView and ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make TextView inside toolbar and set gravity as you want. for your problem it is not necessary to take toolbar, you can also use layout. This is my coordinate layout. In which you can easily adjust TextView inside toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    <!-- app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Dhakar Matrimonial"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/middium_text_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_chat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/middium_padding"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_universerch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:src="@mipmap/search" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: worked , thank you.which way is better you think ؟ this way or layout

Comment: @NimaKhalili you can put `imageview` or `Textview` under the layout. if you want to keep the view relatively then you should use for more customization.

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```