# How to align title or label in Activity in xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am easily able to set Action bar Title in xamarin Android as follows

```
[Activity(Label="My App")]
```

How can I align above label in center?

Comment: There are a lot of answers for that in SO. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347341/how-to-align-center-the-title-or-label-in-activity or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-center-align-the-actionbar-title-in-android and much more. You can easily convert those to Xamarin code

Answer (score 0):

As Yuri S suggested, if your `Activity` is subclass of `AppCompatActivity`, then you may code for example `SupportActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.mytoolbar);` to apply your custom action bar.

But if you want to inherit your activity from default `Activity`, you can also create your own `Toolbar` for action bar, and then in the `OnCreate` of your activity, code like this:

```cs
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
ActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.mytoolbar);
```